# Exporting Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have just discovered pandas and am impressed by its capabilities. 
I am having difficulties  understanding how to work with DataFrame with MultiIndex.

I have two questions :

**(1) Exporting the DataFrame**

Here my problem: 
This dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO
d1 = StringIO.StringIO(
     """Gender,Employed,Region,Degree
     m,yes,east,ba
     m,yes,north,ba
     f,yes,south,ba
     f,no,east,ba
     f,no,east,bsc
     m,no,north,bsc
     m,yes,south,ma
     f,yes,west,phd
     m,no,west,phd
     m,yes,west,phd """
   )

df = pd.read_csv(d1)

# Frequencies tables
tab1 = pd.crosstab(df.Gender, df.Region)
tab2 = pd.crosstab(df.Gender, [df.Region, df.Degree])
tab3 = pd.crosstab([df.Gender, df.Employed], [df.Region, df.Degree])

# Now we export the datasets 
tab1.to_excel('H:/test_tab1.xlsx')  # OK 
tab2.to_excel('H:/test_tab2.xlsx') # fails 
tab3.to_excel('H:/test_tab3.xlsx') # fails
```

One work-around I could think of is to change the columns (The way R does)

```
def NewColums(DFwithMultiIndex):
       NewCol = []
       for item in DFwithMultiIndex.columns:
               NewCol.append('-'.join(item))
       return NewCol 

# New Columns 
tab2.columns = NewColums(tab2)
tab3.columns = NewColums(tab3)

# New export  
tab2.to_excel('H:/test_tab2.xlsx')  # OK
tab3.to_excel('H:/test_tab3.xlsx')  # OK
```

*My question is : Is there a more efficient way to do this in Pandas that I missed in the documentation ?*

**2) Selecting columns**

This new structure does not allow to select colums on a given variable (the advantage of hierarchical indexing in first place). How can I select columns containing a given string (e.g. '-ba') ?

P.S: I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041411/) which is related but have not understood the reply proposed

Comment: Interestingly `tab2.T.to_excel` works, so it's only column MultIndex which is an issue.

Comment: @hayden: thanks for updating the links. the function is indeed handy for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `to_excel`, for the moment as a workaround I would recommend using `to_csv` (which seems not to show this issue).

*I added this as [an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2701).*

To answer the second question, if you *really* need to use `to_excel`...

You can use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to select only those columns which include `'-ba'`:

```
In [21]: filter(lambda x: '-ba' in x, tab2.columns)
Out[21]: ['east-ba', 'north-ba', 'south-ba']

In [22]: tab2[filter(lambda x: '-ba' in x, tab2.columns)]
Out[22]: 
        east-ba  north-ba  south-ba
Gender                             
     f        1         0         1
     m        1         1         0
```

Comment: thanks. also relieved to know that I had not overseen something in the documentation.